# Could not find file ${libs.jstl11.classpath} to copy

Tags: java, netbeans, jstl, classpath, netbeans-7

Good day guys. I have this project in netbeans that when I try to run, it gives out an error message: `"Warning: Could not find file C:\wamp\folder1\${libs.jstl11.classpath} to copy. BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)`
I tried adding jstl-1.2.1.jar to the project's library but it still gets the same error. I also downloaded a jstl11.jar and added it again to project's library but it still don't work. Any other suggestions on how I can resolve this? I'm using netbeans 7.4, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I too faced the same problem.

1. Select the project in the netbeans and right click and navigate to properties.
2. Navigate to libraries, you should see in compile tab that the mentioned library is missing.
3. Remove the missing library and add a new library of JSTL which you have downloaded or choose from  JSTL library options given by netbeans.
4. Save the settings and clean and build the project. Now you should not get the error.

Please let me know if it worked

Comment: Went through so many solutions.. finally got what was required.. And to think it was so simple!

Comment: Remove the missing library x)